# How to know which Maven modules were changed in SCM?

Tags: java, maven

Imagine I have a Maven project with the following structure:

```
-- Client (Used as dependency in other projects to communicate with Server)
---- pom.xml
-- Common (Domain module with classes used by both Client and Server)
---- pom.xml
-- Server (Actual application that is deployed and served in production)
---- pom.xml
pom.xml
```

Both Server and Client depend on Common.

I'm looking for a solution where my CI solution (Jenkins) is able to evaluate if there were any changes in any of the children modules in my SCM since the respective's build last successful build (not sure the best way to track this last successful build, maybe using git tags). This is because I have different behaviours in my pipeline for each module, and I don't want to unnecessarily run all of them when only one was changed. The behaviour I expect is the following:

- If Client was changed, install the Client module and deploy to a remote Nexus. (the Client's shading process already includes the Common module, so there is no need to also deploy that one).
- If Server was changed, install the Server module and have it deployed to production the Server's shading process also already includes the Common module)
- If Common was changed, install both the Client and Server's modules and deploy them.

It is not relevant I update the version of the Server module in pom.xml, but I do need to keep track of the version in the Client module (since it's used as a dependency in other projects).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the SCM providers now support web hooks, You can trigger a jenkins job whenever there is a merge into your master branch.

Now as part of the jenkins build you can use SCM provider's rest api interface ([bitbucket](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/command-line-rest/) and [github](https://developer.github.com/v3/) provide rest apis) that can be used to figure out which modules have changed, Once you know the modules that were changed you can then build and deploy them selectively.